# JS event listener stops working when child divs are added, only last div event listener works

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm working on a arbitrary project, and I'm trying to only use vanilla JS because I'm a masochist. I have it set up to display a list of items, each with a button to add the item to to the 'cart'. When they get added to the cart each a new div containing the item information and a button is pushed into the sidebar div. When the button for the add item to cart is pushed it makes a call to the function that adds the event listener to the remove item button which have their own unique id's. My problem is once more items are added to the cart, only the last item's remove button works. Here's the relevant bit of JS:

This sets the eventListeners for the add to cart buttons:

```
function setupItemClickHandlers(items) {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('add-cart');
    var i; 

    function generateItemClickHandler(itemNumber) {
        return function clickHandler() {
            // does things to the objects
            setupCartItemClickHandlers(itemCartNum);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', generateItemClickHandler(i));
    }
}
```

And the code that sets the remove items buttons event listeners (Note: I added the format function to String's prototype, the unique numbers are getting inserted there):

```
function setupCartItemClickHandlers(itemNum){
    var elCartItem = document.getElementById('item-{0}'.format(itemNum));
    var removeButton = document.getElementById('remove-{0}'.format(itemNum));

    function generateRemoveClickHandler(itemNum) {
        return function clickHandler() {
            // Does what it needs to do
        }
    }

    removeButton.addEventListener('click', generateRemoveClickHandler(itemNum));
}
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4p1o4rmf/1/)

Comment: Can you create a simple plnkr or fiddle? It should be easily possible and will also contain the relevant HTML

Comment: Is `itemCartNum` inside `generateItemClickHandler` a typo??

Comment: @devnull69 [Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4p1o4rmf/1/). I'm pretty new to JS and thought I understood the closure thing, evidently I don't.

Comment: Since your a vanillajs dev I'd recommend using: https://github.com/eorroe/NodeList.js

Answer (score 0):

You can create (like jQuery live/on) event listener, only one time, for parent of items of cart with event.target and event.srcElement